# What does “status pending” mean in the Cognito forms entries?

Tags: cognito-forms

In the Cognito forms entries, what does “status pending” mean and how does it change to complete?

I have notice that all entries are pending, even my test samples.

Answer (score 1):

Entries in [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com) can have an Entry Status of either Pending or Complete.  All entries initially have a Entry Status of Pending, but administrators can mark entries as Complete when they have finished processing an entry.  You can also quickly filter entries by Entry Status, which makes it easy to work through the current pending list.

We plan to leverage this Entry Status in the future to support additional features, including [Save & Resume](https://trello.com/c/Bk6swilY), where entries that have been saved but not yet submitted would have a different Entry Status, and [workflow](https://trello.com/c/AtfEqasG), where you may be able to define your own Entry Status options and trigger notifications and approval processes.

This Entry Status is separate from the Payment Status, which tracks whether an entry has been paid.  This is helpful when you need to fulfill orders, as the Payment Status might be Paid if paid online when the entry was submitted or Unpaid if a cash or check option was selected.  Separate from payment, you would use the Entry Status to determine if the goods or services had actually been delivered to the customer.

This is how filtering by Entry and/or Payment Status looks when managing entries:

[image]

Comment: Hi Jamie, I don't have a green arrow to change the status.
I see it in the documentation:
http://help.cognitoforms.com/working-with-pending-and-completed-entries

Comment: You should see this in one of two places.  When the grid is expanded, the last column should show the status with the option to click to change the status.  If it is not appearing in this view, please let us know.  When you are looking at a specific entry, the status appears in the top right, allowing you to change the status.  Please note that you cannot change the status for Incomplete entries-those that are saved but not submitted via Save & Resume.

Comment: I see the Status edit arrow on our tourism form, but not on our creative services form.

Comment: Also, you must have Editor permissions for the form to change the status.  If you are an Administrator or Editor for the form, then please submit a bug report so we can work with you to fix the issue.